# Is it possible to read a request header from client javascript?

Tags: javascript, browser, client

It it possible to read the request headers ? The same vars you can see from a debugger like Chrome's developer console:

[image]

Something like console.log(headers['accept-enconding']);

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/5fbffn8s/

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: What i am looking is not a "new" request, but the page from the page that renders initially, before i am able to make a ajax request.