# Is it possible to read the request headers using Javascript in a Browser?

Tags: javascript, http, amazon-s3, static, http-headers

I have a S3 static page in a bucket and have added a Cloudfront distribution in front of it to access the webpage.

Now my question is: Is it possible to read the headers received by the webpage when the page is loaded? Is there a way I can print the headers on the webpage ?

Note: Im NOT about the response headers or the request headers before making a call from the client like mentioned over here: [Accessing the web page's HTTP Headers in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-the-web-pages-http-headers-in-javascript)

Im asking the same question as over here: [Is it possible to read a request header from client javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47138769/is-it-possible-to-read-a-request-header-from-client-javascript) for which there is no answer

Comment: Never mind I just understood that it is not possible from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I access the HTTP request header fields via JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220149/how-do-i-access-the-http-request-header-fields-via-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access to the `HTTP` headers from your script, and this is the reason. `HTTP` is a client-server protocol, the server which receives the `HTTP` request headers is the S3 `HTTP` server. An `HTTP GET` request looks like this:

```
GET /index.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.yours3bucketurl.com
User-Agent: client name
```

As you can see, the `HTTP` server uses that header to determine, what resource it should response with, in this case `index.html`. Then that `index.html` page is sent to the client and the request is over. There is not a chance that the `JavaScript` code contained in, or called from `index.html`, have access to that `HTTP GET` request, only the server knows. In other words, the content of `index.html` is just a resource returned from an `HTTP` server.